# Android : Resume last shown Activity from Notification

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating Notification in my application.

How can I resume my app from its previous position (Open previously paused activity)

```
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);    
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.txlogo, "My App",  System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "My App", "simple notification", pendingIntent);
// and this
final int HELLO_ID = 1;
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

But in above case when i clicked on Notification it is opening "LoginActivity"

i need to resume last shown Activity.

Comment: You can save some identifier in SharedPreference and use it to identify the last activity.

Comment: yes, i did the same thing. but unable to fetch bundle. as it giving null value.